# What is the hook angle on a saw blade?

Tags: safety, table-saw, tools, saw-blade, radial-arm-saw

One of the specs listed on saw blades is the *hook angle*. What does this mean, and when would you choose one over the other?

Comment: Just a small aside which may help more people find this question - the "hook angle" as you call it is sometimes also referred to (at least here in the UK and I believe in the rest of Europe) as the "rake angle".

Answer (score 13):

The hook angle refers to the angle at which the teeth will engage the material being cut. A high or positive hook angle means the outermost tip of each tooth will engage very aggressively, whereas a low or negative hook angle causes each tooth to take a less aggressive bite.

[image: hook angle]

([Source](http://www.rockler.com/how-to/blades-101/))

**How do I choose a blade based on hook angle?**

Use a blade with a negative hook angle for tools that make climb cuts, such as radial arm saws.  A radial arm saw is more difficult to control and will try to cut faster than you want it to, if the installed blade has a positive hook angle. A negative hook angle is also useful for cutting certain materials such as metal on a table saw.

Use a blade with a positive hook angle for faster, more aggressive cuts, such as ripping boards on a table saw.